# Android - AnyObject for Android like iOS Swift 2

Tags: android, ios, anyobject

I need help, This is example for AnyObject Class in Swift.

```
class OtherClass {
   private var myValue: String?
   func setValue(myValue: String) {
      self.myValue = myValue
   }
   func getValue() -> String {
      return myValue!
   }
}

class MyClass {
   init() {
      let otherClass = OtherClass()
      otherClass.setValue("Value here!")
      let myValue = getValue(otherClass) as? String
      print(myValue) // output is Value here!
   }
   func getValue(object: AnyObject) -> AnyObject {
      let myObject = object as! OtherClass
      return myObject.getValue()
   }
}
```

We can add OtherClass object to parameter of getValue method. You can see, the parameter method is AnyObject not OtherClass. But in android i cannot do that. So, is possible use AnyObject Class in Android like in iOS ?

Comment: the question is not clear enough, what do you mean? you might want to edit it...

Comment: You want the [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Java Object class. Otherwise you can create your own class, extended by all `OtherClass` and use it as input type parameter.

You could give a look to [Java Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) too (but it's more advanced and maybe it's not useful in this case)

[Swift AnyObject Doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anyobject):

> The protocol to which all classes implicitly conform.

[Java Object Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html):

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

Comment: Perfect answer!
Thanks a lot @lubilis. This is solved my problem.